# How to define a chemical bond computationally?

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory, glass

I'm working with an amorphous system. With oxygen, my system has both covalent and ionic bond forming cations. I utilise the [Wannier centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wannier_function) to define a covalent bond, and my theory is that if the Wannier centre is near to the line connecting the cation and anion, it is a covalent bond.

However, this method fails to identify an ionic bond as there is no region of high electronic charge density which can be localized to obtain Wannier center. How can an ionic bond be defined using a computational technique?

Comment: Matter Modeling is likely a better place to ask this.

Comment: I think you have to think carefully about what you mean by an ionic bond. For instance using the ionic model to describe MgO I would argue that, as the coulomb potential is very long ranged and can't be truncated, the oxygens sit in the potential minimum due to *all* the other ions in the lattice. So are all oxygens (and hence all the magnesiums) bonded to everything else? Often for ionic species a simple A bonds to B pairwise view of the world is not that useful

Comment: Have a look at the Quantum Theory of Atoms in Molecules. It might help you along.